# Service Bus SQL Filter apparently not working in Azure Functions v3

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I created a topic "Messages" in my service bus instance, and added a new subscription to it. I can send messages to this topic and the Azure Function v3 trigger is activated just fine. The message is received and displayed in an instant.
When I add an sql filter to filter messages for a subscription it is not working anymore.

What I did so far.
Created an sql filter in the azure portal:

```
sys.Label = "Test" -> Not working as no messages are received anymore, even though I verified that the Label attribute is set.

sys.Label != "Test" Not working as no messages are received anymore, even though I verified that the Label attribute is set and not matching "Test"

sys.To = "Test" -> Not working, no messages are received. Verified that the messages contain the To member.

sys.Label is not Null -> This is strangely working.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: As this was Addressed in the Microsoft Q&A you can refer the latest discussion by referring the below Q&A community link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/469038/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, the solution to this question can be found in the [Microsoft Q&A.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/469038/syslabel-34test34-is-not-working-in-azure-portal.html?childToView=471441#answer-471441)

To prevent a loss of this solution I am going to post it here too:

The SQL filter value should be in single quotes 'test'

> Example : sys.To = 'test'
>
> Make sure that you are defining the message system properties while
> sending the message to topic.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/469038/syslabel-34test34-is-not-working-in-azure-portal.html?childToView=471441#answer-471441)

If someone is caught off guard by the red single quotes. They are just red, but don't indicate that something is wrong with it. It will just work fine.